# How do i go about counting how many times a messagebox appears in c#?

Tags: c#, counting

I am trying to get my program to Count how many times a certain messagebox in my program appears while it is running.

I have looked up how to do this and it seems that I will need to use int count but I'm not sure how to code this for Messageboxes as I can only find count code for strings and arrays.

Comment: declare a global varaiable, and every time you call `MessageBox.Show()`, increment it.

Comment: It would be better to declare a simple new class that wraps MessageBox with a field for the number of times its been shown.

Comment: @JW. C# doesn't have globals.

Comment: seems like for login user function. attempt 1, attempt 2, attemp 3?

Comment: @TheGreatCO theres a global variable http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable

Comment: @spajce Those are static variables that are members of a static class.  They are not global in the sense of C++ and C globals.

Comment: @TheGreatCO But this is C#, why draw comparatives with irrelevant languages? A 'global' variable in C# is still a thing, conceptually, just differently.

Comment: @TheGreatCO sounds like you're referring from this [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/3ea35ea5-6912-44f0-828a-666cb12c6e0c). so what is your understanding from this [information](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable)?

Answer (score 3):

It is better idea to make some static wrapper class for MessageBox class and count it there in some kind of static variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this

1- create a class `Adapter` that wraps `MessageBox` class, add a counter field to the Adapter and increment it in every call

```
 class MyMessageBox
 {
 static int counter;

 static void Show(string msg)
 {
   counter++;
   MessageBox.Show(msg);
 }
 }
```

using this approach you assume  that users are using your MessageBox

2- The second solution is `AOP`
   use an `Aspect Oriented` framework like `PostSharp` to count `Show` calls