# Get Global variables list in a class and namespace

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have following class.

```
  namespace Automate
{
    class Class1
    {
        private bool global1;
        private bool global2;
        public void Method(bool param1)
        {
            bool flag = false;
        }
    }
    class Class2
    {
        private bool global1;
        private bool global2;
        public void Method(bool param1)
        {
            bool flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want all the global variables of class 1 & 2 but not local variables.

for example

```
Class1 : Global1,Global2
Class2 : Global1,Global2
```

Out Put Should not contain

```
`flag & param1`
```

How can i write Regex to do it?

Comment: are you attempting reflection?  I'm a bit confused on what you are actually asking.

Comment: In what way are those private instance variables "global" variables? Note that you can't derive a class from two different classes in C#.

Comment: There are no global variables in C#. There are static fields or instance fields or constants in classes.

Comment: @sircapsalot I get the impression this is literal text parsing.

Comment: The classes are identical except in name. Why are they different? If you want to override implementation details in c# you'll need to use inheritance. This looks like a situation where you potentially need an abstract base class.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger As per my comment on another thread where someone made this misnomic assumption of 'no global variables in C#': "A 'global' variable in C# is still a thing, conceptually, just differently". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313794/how-do-i-go-about-counting-how-many-times-a-messagebox-appears-in-c#comment21618518_15313794 I dare say, prefixing variable names with the literal 'global' isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class1 c1 = new class1();
            FieldInfo[] fields = c1.GetType().GetFields(
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                         BindingFlags.Instance);
            Console.WriteLine("class1");
            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            }

            class2 c2 = new class2();
            fields = c2.GetType().GetFields(
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                         BindingFlags.Instance);

            Console.WriteLine("class2");
            foreach (FieldInfo fi in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class class1
    {
        private string field1;
        private string field2;

        private void a(string hello)
        {

        }
    }

    public class class2
    {
        private string field3;
        private string field4;

        private void a(string hello)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the generic names I threw this together very quickly. Also re-reading the question you want a way to do this with a regex instead not sure what you mean by that but my above example will get you what you want right ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the code in your question as a text file, and you want to "grep" the fields of each class from them.

If you assume that each field is declared on one line and has an access modifier in front of it, this is very easy. You simply grep on

```
(public|internal|protected|private)[^(){}]*;
```

The `[^(){}]` part makes sure we don't get properties or methods.

However, fields can also be declared without access modifier:

```
class Class3 
{
    bool someBool;
    public void Method() {
        bool someBool;
    }
}
```

As you see, the code declaring the field and the code declaring variable in `Method` are exactly the same. It is thus not possible to retrieve only the field using a regex.

One way to solve this is to look for the `class` keyword, and count the number of curly braces after that. If you have encountered one `{`, you are in class scope and you can grep for fields. If you encountered two `{`, you are probably in a method. Of course you also have to take `}` into account, because fields may not be declared at the top of the class.

This gives problems when the code has a curly brace in a string literal, because then your braces no longer match. To really really solve this problem, you need a [C# parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81406/parser-for-c-sharp) or [C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: Does your 'no properties' contingency account of index properties? i.e. `Item[int index]`.